# Time period in group by Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a query that group by datetime , I want to group by datetime and  time period.(morning , evening)

```
from f in _db.Visits
where f.VisitDate >= sdate && f.VisitDate <= edate
group f by new { f.VisitDate, f.Personnel }
into myGroup
where myGroup.Any()
 select new
   {
    myGroup.Key.VisitDate,
    myGroup.Key.Personnel.Name,
    myGroup.Key.Personnel.Family,
    VisitType = myGroup.GroupBy(f => f.VisitTypeId).Select
    (m => new { Count = m.Count(), Id = m.Key, Total = m.Sum(c => c.Amount) })
    }
```

for example, select items of 2015/10/10 morning , 2015/10/10 evening

Comment: Linq-to-Sql or Entity Framework? Note that `where myGroup.Any()` is useless. A group to exist MUST have at least one element :)

Comment: Thanks , Linq to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
group f by new 
{
    VisitDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f.VisitDate), 
    Morning = f.VisitDate.Hour < 13, 
    f.PersonnelId 
}
```

Where 13 is the hour where you truncate morning with afternoon.

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f.VisitDate)
```

returns the date without the time (note that with EF < 6.0 you'll have to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(f.VisitDate))`, and

```
f.VisitDate.Hour
```

returns the hour of the date, so

```
f.VisitDate.Hour < 13
```

is `true` in the morning and `false` in the afternoon